# How to filter a Django ORM query using an annotation against a model attribute?

Tags: django-orm

I have a Model with an attribute containing an Int capacity, and a FK relationship to manage the utilisation, as follows:

```
class Container(Model):
    objects = ContainerManager()

    capacity = PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)



class Item(Model):
    container = ForeignKey('Container', related_name='items'
```

The Manager needs to find containers that have spare capacity i.e. the number of Items associated with the Container. I am using an annotation to count the Items, but cannot work out how to compare this with the capacity i.e. something like this..

```
get_queryset().annotate(utilisation=Count('items').filter(capacity__gt=utilisation)
```

Is this possible in one query?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm answering my own question in case it helps others.. the solution is to use an F() expression..

```
get_queryset().annotate(utilisation=Count('items').filter(capacity__gt=F(utilisation))
```